# Multilingual WebForms Maintained in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, forms, multilingual

This question is for someone hopefully with experience in what I'm trying to accomplish.

**GOAL**:

I have a webform with several drop-down-lists, in English, developed on ASP.NET.

- User 1: Select their desired options, then submits the English values to the SQL Server database.
- User 2: Then chooses a language in which to view a printable version of the form. The English values then get translated to the selected language for printing (presumably via some XML files for extensibility).

Is using XML files for translation a good approach, or is their a better solution?

- If this is a good approach, any suggestions on how to implement it?
- If this is a bad approach, **what is the best way**?

Comment: @Jeroen: Please review my changes. I flubbed. To answer your question though, it's because I want to keep the DB entirely in English for maintainability. I just thought for simple translations it would be better to store those in XML format. Is this bad?

Comment: Wow! These are all AMAZING recommendations guys. I'm going to have a hard time choosing just one answer on this one. It'll probably be the one I think will most benefit others who find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming items are unique for each dropdown. I think you need only 3 tables.

```
* for the dropdowns (dropdownid, name)
* for the dropdown items (dropdownitemid, dropdownid)
* for the translated items. (id, dropdownitemid, text, culturecode)
```

As for the locale i would a culturecode instead of separate table. Eeach HttpRequest comes with a cultureinfo that is set to the user's browser language. something like 'en-US'. Using this code in your table with let you effectivly select the right language.

Comment: I was actually looking into the CultureUI class. I want ONLY the printable form to be translated though. The actual user interface should remain English. Will this work with your suggested structure?

Comment: Yes, one page you can pull all data with culturecode 'en-US' and on the page for printing you use the user's culturecode. (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)

Comment: I finally got back to this and it seems your solution is the simplest while meeting my needs. Thanks ;) Now I just have to work out the bugs in my SP for inserting new Lists, Items, and Translations and I'll be set.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do it this way:

Have 4 tables

```
1) Dropdown (DropdownID, DropdownName, etc)
2) DropdownItems (DropdownItemID, DropDownItemName)
3) Dropdown_DropdownItems (DropdownID, DropdownItemID)
4) Locales (localeID, LocaleName)
5) DropdownItems_Locales(DropdownItemID, LocaleId, LocalText)
```

this way, you have a unique id to each dropdownitem (DropdownItemID). you join tables 1, 2, 5 to get localized text for dropdown item for the selected locale, but the dropdownitemid remain same in all languages. This is far more maintainable, and extensible.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I think it MAY be a bit more than I need for my purposes though, but certainly a more complete and robust answer. Thanks :)

Comment: im using this approach for a similar requirement, and no complaints till now :)